# What are some good chess resources to learn from?

Tags: beginner, recommendations

I have looked in a lot of places, but I can't find good places to learn chess. I am at the stage where I know basic chess strategies, but my rating is still below average. I can't find a source longer than a short article to learn from. Do you have any suggestions? I can't really pay for things (my main roadblock,  but I can if I have to.

Comment: See also: [Books that explain fundamental chess concepts](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/41104/26335) and [Where can one find a complete chess curriculum?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/39875/26335)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm an older player (84), but in my youth I read several chess manuals which explained all the basics and gave hints for improvement, such as books by I.A.Horowitz, Fred Reinfeld and Reuben Fine.  These are still available on eBay at reasonable prices.  And there are certainly more modern books that cover the same area, by Bruce Pandolfini, Jeremy Sillman, and Yasse Seirawan for example. But now in the era of the computer and the Internet, there is a readily available source of this information at your fingertips.  Just Google tips for chess improvement.  GM Arthur Bisguier for instance has written "Ten Tips for Winning Chess" which you can find there. And I'm sure there are countless others.  Then there's "YouTube" which has many free chess tutorials and also game analyses, such as by Agadmator and Mato.  I watch them there myself. Those are all good starting places. And of course you have to supplement what you learn by applying it in actual play.  Good luck on your chess journey!

Answer (score 2):

Remember.. No question is dumb

It really depends which chess learning stage you are.. If you are absolute beginner , either sign up for chess lessons on some popular chess websites. Understand the basics of chess. How to move pieces , rules of chess , Openings , Middle Game and Endgame.

Once you learn all that and become an intermediate player , learn about variations in openings , tactics in Middle Game and How to win Endgames.

I hope these two phases should keep you busy for a relatively long time.

I run a chess channel on youtube however I am not a chess expert and I am also learning just like you. I do share some of the chess content that I study. Feel free to watch those videos. But remember , if you want to learn chess , study books and sign up for a good chess website.

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfBrplys3U5FMAHHkbGmhGg

Answer (score 2):

The [Practice](https://lichess.org/practice) section on Lichess has some nice interactive lessons. If you like this format, you can also take a look at the top [Lichess Studies](https://lichess.org/study), which are really good as well.

I also want to mention a few instructive YouTube channels:

- [GothamChess](https://www.youtube.com/c/GothamChess)
- [ChessNetwork](https://www.youtube.com/ChessNetworkTV)
- [Agadmator](https://www.youtube.com/c/AGADMATOR)
- [Eric Rosen](https://www.youtube.com/user/RosenChess)
- [GMHikaru](https://www.youtube.com/c/GMHikaru)
- [thechesswebsite](https://www.youtube.com/c/chesswebsite)
- [Chess School (MatoJelic)](https://www.youtube.com/c/MatoJelic)
- [ChessWhiz TV](https://www.youtube.com/c/ChessWhizTV)

There is also [Chessable](https://www.chessable.com). Since you are unable to spend money, you can take a look at their [free courses](https://www.chessable.com/courses/all/all/free/).

---

Also, there are a lot of great questions on here which include other great resources for learning. Here is a list of some of the best ones:

- [In Chess, are there simple "mechanics" that amateurs can learn to improve their game?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1270/in-chess-are-there-simple-mechanics-that-amateurs-can-learn-to-improve-their)
- [What are some resources for someone past beginner but not yet intermediate?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/15698/what-are-some-resources-for-someone-past-beginner-but-not-yet-intermediate)
- [How to improve from ~1200?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/27897/how-to-improve-from-1200)
- [Books that help improve your chess without a chessboard](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/books-that-help-improve-your-chess-without-a-chessboard)
- [What book should I refer to to begin learning chess?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/6228/what-book-should-i-refer-to-to-begin-learning-chess)
- [Best chess theory books for beginners](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1981/best-chess-theory-books-for-beginners)
- [Where can I start to learn?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5208/where-can-i-start-to-learn)
- [What are some good tactics books?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39211/what-are-some-good-tactics-books)
- [How can I improve my knowledge of pawn structure theory?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/22971/how-can-i-improve-my-knowledge-of-pawn-structure-theory)
- [Chess books for master level players](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8971/chess-books-for-master-level-players)
- [What are some good books for chess openings?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4749/what-are-some-good-books-for-chess-openings)
- [What is the best way to play the middlegame?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39185/what-is-the-best-way-to-play-the-middlegame)
- [How do I learn to understand the middlegame?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/how-do-i-learn-to-understand-the-middlegame)
- [Which endgame manual?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29027/which-endgame-manual)
- [Endgame books or web-sources](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/14530/endgame-books-or-web-sources)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner-level chess enthusiast and have recently started learning the game. One book I've found incredibly helpful and enjoyable is "Encyclopedic Manual of the Game of Chess" by Mikhail Tal and Nikolai Zhuravlev.

Answer (score 0):

[KorpalskiChess.com](https://korpalskichess.com/?page_id=61138) has a lot of interactive exercises carefully selected by a chess coach.