# What are some good tactics books?

Tags: learning, books, beginner, recommendations

I am looking for books with exercises to improve at tactics. It seems that there are lots of options.

My definition of what constitutes a “good” tactics books is variety. Even if the book focuses on a specific puzzle type (like checkmate puzzles), I believe a good book will have a great variety of positions in different stages of the game where different tactical ideas are required.

I also prefer books with some explanation or analysis on why certain moves may or may not work, not just the diagrams and moves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following books are extremely suited for beginner players seeking to improve tactics. At least two of these are available on Chessable for those seeking digital options.

- *Everyone's First Chess Workbook*:  good for board vision, learning patterns, themed chapters by motif, builds to more difficult puzzles that combine themes. Answers include explanations and some details on relevant variations.
- *Winning Chess Tactics*: Topical chapters with tests on learning throughout book, with two chapters at end to take as exams and compare against scoring rubric. Second exam at end will be a challenge to beginners.

The series by Polgar is also often recommended for beginners ([Perpetual Chess podcast recommendations](https://www.perpetualchesspod.com/book-recommendations)).

- *Learn Chess the Right Way: Book 1 Must Know Checkmates*
- *Learn Chess the Right Way: Book 2 Winning Material*

[image: Book covers]

<sub>I hesitate to include Seirawan's *Play Winning Chess* in the image as it isn't really a tactics book, but prepares readers a bit for his *Winning Chess Tactics* books. I imagine some in the community may say *Play Winning Chess* isn't a tactics book, and they are probably right. It seems to be in the spirit of your question though, and designed for beginner players.</sub>

Additionally, the [Chess Steps](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/39879/26335) series of workbooks are filled with puzzles. Tactics, board vision, checkmates, and defense are recurring themes.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent for novices are Dan Heisman's books. My favorite of his was ***Back to Basics : Tactics*** . I have nostalgia for Seirawan's ***Winning Chess Tactics*** as it was the first chess book I read all the way through. Sent both to my grandsons. For more advanced study consider one of Weteschnik's books, although they are limited in the breadth of tactics they cover.