# i need help about the lesson plans or the curriculum to follow to teach chess

Tags: coach

I was a chess coach working in organizations. Now I would like to start my own. I need help about the chess curriculum or lesson plan and the platform to use to teach. Also are there any courses for chess coaches.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per question. I would also strongly urge you to use the site's search function. In the top left hand side of the screen, where it says "Search on Chess..." you can type your search word or phrase and press enter. You may find that your questions have already been asked and answered.

Comment: Check Here
https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39875/where-can-one-find-a-complete-chess-curriculum

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [Chess Steps Method & Curriculum](https://www.chess-steps.eu/home.php) - from beginner to Master level (all ages)

> "Chess-Steps is a step by step method for teaching and learning chess.
> The combination of workbook and manual creates a school like
> situation. All lessons are structured and contain clear goals. The
> books cover everything from how the pieces move in Step 1 to important
> endgame strategies in Step 5 and 6. Most attention is given to
> tactics. The strength of Chess-Steps is that it chops all tactics into
> little building blocks. Solving a chess problem with a subject is
> significantly easier than a problem without. Not only are all tactics
> categorized, Chess-Steps offers a search strategy for every subject as
> well. Students will develop a feeling for tactical positions, a sense
> for when to be alert and take advantage of badly placed pieces"

For a great online resource targeted at kids consider [Chesskid](https://www.chesskid.com/resources/for-teaching), great curriculum and great teaching resources.