# Can you suggest book references on chess theory?

Tags: theory, books, mathematics, recommendations, reference-request

as stated in the title I am looking for structured textbooks on chess. I have followed chess.com lessons and I have a rough idea of tactics (forks, pins, skewers, sacrifices, etc) but I feel like I am missing something.

Is there any book that seriously expose the theory of chess, like an academic text would do?

Comment: Possibly Relevant:  (1) [Where can one find a complete chess curriculum?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/39875/26335), (2) [Books that explain fundamental chess concepts](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/41104/26335)

Answer (score 2):

Almost, every book of chess is about chess theory. There are millions!

One fantastic collection is Yusupov Complete Series: https://www.qualitychess.co.uk/products/13/195/yusupov_complete_series_in_hardcover/

Arthur Yusupov is one of the greatest chess players of all time. Moreover, this collection won several prizes for its high quality.

My advise would be to start with book#1: ***Build up your Chess 1.***

The same collection is available on Chessable that is a website that uses a very friendly format.  Also, you can access it in any part of the world immediately. Additionally, [www.chessable.com](http://www.chessable.com) gives you a 30 day trial: https://www.chessable.com/the-fundamentals-1-build-up-your-chess/course/19145/

I have returned several books that I did not like without a problem.

If you prefer the classic format, the editorial of Yusupov gives you an exceprt. You can find it in this link: https://www.qualitychess.co.uk/ebooks/Build-up-Your-Chess-1-exceprt.pdf

https://www.qualitychess.co.uk/products/2/16/build_up_your_chess_1_-_artur_yusupov/

Good luck in your chess journey!

[image: Yusupov: Build-up-Your-Chess-1]